# How can I read SoapHeader in BeforeDeserialize in WebService

Tags: c#

How can I read SoapHeader in BeforeDeserialize, I try this, but it does not work. Any solution or simple example. Thank you.

```
    public class TicketIdentity
    {
        private string ticket;

        public string Ticket
        {
            get { return ticket; }
        }

        public TicketIdentity(string _ticket)
        {
            this.ticket = _ticket;
        }
    }

    public class TicketHeader : SoapHeader
    {
        public string Ticket;
        public TicketHeader(string ticket)
        {
            Ticket = ticket;
        }
        public TicketHeader()
        { }
    }

...

   string Key;

        public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
        {
            switch (message.Stage)
            {
                case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize:
                    break;
                case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize:
                    break;
                case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize:
                    {
                     foreach (SoapHeader header in message.Headers)
                         {
                         if (header is TicketHeader)
                            {
                            TicketHeader tempHeader = (TicketHeader)header;
                            Key = tempHeader.Ticket;
                            }
                         }
                    }
                    break;
                case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize:
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Chyba pri serializacii SOAP msg.");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before deserializing, the headers are also serialized, because they are in the form of . Therefore you cannot compare the headers to business objects, because the message needs to be deserialized to do that.

Comment: So, Is any solution, How can I read SoapHeader in BeforeDeserialize??

Comment: No this is not possible, nor should you try do it in that place. Why do you want to do this ondeserialization anyhow?

Comment: I add own SoapHeder in Soap message, and I need value form SoapHeader in BeforeDesesialize...that's all